# Optimisation by using directional derivative

Tags: r, optimization, derivative, gradient

So I’ve seen the code of an R package where a two dimensional optimisation (actually MLE, finding the minimum of the negative log likelihood) is performed with the *optim* function and also two *optimise* functions to find the initial values for that *optim* function. That is, let $F(x,y)$ be the function whose min to be sought, first fixed $y=y_0$ (some constant) and find $x$ with *optimise*. Then $x$ is fixed at this optimised value and find $y$ with *optimise*. If, on the top of these two *optimise* along the $x$ and $y$ axis, can the initial values of *optim* be further improved by optimising along, say, diagonally with the use of directional derivative?

Comment: It depends on the context and assumptions.  Your description sounds like repeated conditioning on variables, which is used in certain MLE settings.  It would be justified when the problem is *strictly locally convex.*  In that case, there's no possible improvement to be made by searching in any other directions, because the package's method will wind up at a local minimum (which will be global when the problem is globally convex).  It is easy to construct non-convex optimization problems where searching along coordinate directions does not yield local minima.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, steepest gradient descent is a popular method that improve its solution by moving along the steepest descent direction.

Also, you can for instance be creative and let it move along other directions and solve a small optimization problem locally. However, unless the direction that you pick has an advantage (For example, some eigenvector direction or conjugate graidient direction), I don't see the benefits of picking a random direction.